# Hadoop 2.7.2 single node cluster example fails

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm following the single node cluster example from [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution).
Up until step 5 under **Execution** everything works fine, but then I get the following error output:

```
Asafs-MBP:hadoop-2.7.2 asafchelouche$ bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input
16/05/15 17:04:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: `input': No such file or directory
```

don't mind the WARN, I've researched it and it doesn't seem to have any actual negative effect.

I've already consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132233/hadoop-does-not-see-the-input-folder) SO question, but to no avail. It seems that the instruction is wrong: In step 1 of **Execution** you format the file system, so there's no *input* folder. Also, it should be written as `/input` rather than `input`. Am I correct on this matter?
When I do use `/input` (after creating the folder with `bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /input`), I get an enormous stack trace following an exception (see [here](http://pastebin.com/LJVD042s), it's too long to put here).

Why is this, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit - in step #4, I need to run `bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>`. I thought I can use any username I please, but it turns out that inputing the username of the currently running user in the OS would make everything work properly. Have no idea why this matters...

Answer (score 0):

```
hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input
```

This command will attempt to put the `etc/hadoop` file or directory of the local filesystem into the `/user/<username>/input` HDFS directory. Where that username is typically the name of the user you run the command as. Use `whoami` to figure that out.

If you did not make that user directory and subsequent input directory, you'll see that error.

However, your long stacktrace clearly states you have 0 datanodes up and running, so the error seems to be not starting HDFS

Comment: isn't running `sbin/start-dfs.sh` the action that starts HDFS?

Comment: That's correct. You'll also need to start YARN for mapreduce to work. There error message repeatedly says  "There are 0 datanode(s) running"